# Removing a table row with jQuery in rails using a helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This should be easy as lots of people have asked but there answers dont seem to work for me.

I've got a table that a row is added with AJAX. I now want to delete with AJAX.

I have this partial which is added:

```
<tr >
    <td><%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => @project.id ,:disabled => true %></td>
    <td><%= f.select :taskType, ['Pre-Sales','Project','Support','Fault Fixing','Out Of Hours'] %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :task_name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %></td>

</tr>
```

this leads to this helper:

```
def link_to_remove_fields(name, f)
    f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)")
  end

  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
    end
    link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
  end
```

which leads to this js:

```
function remove_fields(link) {
    $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").value = "1";
    $(link).parent(".fields").hide();
    //$(link).find('tr').remove();
    $(link).remove();
}
function add_fields(link, association, content) {  
    var new_id = new Date().getTime();  
    var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");  
    $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));  
}
```

I can get as far as deleting the column with the button delete in it but not the row. I think the way I've done it does not allow for deleting a 'tr`.

I sure this is simple and its just my lack of experience with jQuery that's failing me

**Update**
rendered html

```
<td>
<input id="project_project_tasks_attributes_1315581090843__destroy" type="hidden" value="false" name="project[project_tasks_attributes][1315581090843][_destroy]">
<a onclick="remove_fields(this); return false;" href="#">remove</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
//$(link).find('tr').remove();
```

To

```
$(link).parents('tr').remove();
```

Comment: You'll have to post your rendered HTML and where the link that you're clicking is then I guess, as there is nothing wrong with my code assuming you have `<tr><td><a href="#">remove</a></td></tr>`

Comment: thats exactly what i have... im thinking about just making it an onclick function and have done with

Comment: Umm... onclick function _on what_?  How are you binding your click event to the remove link?

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but all you need to do is put an anchor on the page and unobtrusively attach a click handler to it.  `<a href="#" id="foo">remove</a>`  Then: `$('#foo').click(function() { ... });`  Like I said, look at the _RENDERED_ HTML and see what your link looks like.

Answer (score 0):

## Removing a table row with jQuery in rails without helper

Maybe it will help you

**Controller Destroy Action:**

```
def destroy
    @manufacture = Manufacture.find(params[:id])
    @id = @manufacture.id
    @manufacture.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @manufactures.each do |manufacture| %>
  <tr id="manufacture-row-<%= manufacture.id%>"> 
    <td><%= manufacture.product.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', manufacture, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' },remote: true %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

**destroy.js.erb**

```
$('#manufacture-row-<%= @id %>').remove();
```